# Display my cards in 3 columns using reactjs Material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to retrieve images from an API and display them in a three column grid system. When I retrieved  images, they are displayed one beneath each other.
Kindly advised best way to achieve this

```
import React from "react";
import Display from "./Display";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      image: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=0&_limit=10";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ image: data, loading: false });
    console.log(data);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div> loading ... </div>;
    }
    if (!this.state.image.length) {
      return <div> didnt get an image</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.image.map((img) => (
          <div>
            <div>
              {" "}
              <Display
                showImage={img.url}
                showTitle={img.title}
                showAlbum={img.albumId}
              />{" "}
            </div>
            <div key={img.id}>
              <ul></ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
function Display(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={4}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              alt="Contemplative Reptile"
              height="200"
              width="200"
              img
              src={props.showImage}
            />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                {props.showTitle}
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                Album ID: {props.showAlbum}
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
          <CardActions>
            <Button size="small" color="primary">
              Share
            </Button>
            <Button size="small" color="primary">
              Learn More
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Display;
```

In my App.js I'm able to using the map feature and get all the items from the array, I'm thinking I should modify my App.jS file to print out the results in the three columns but I'm not sure. Can I modify the Display file so that each card goes right beside each other? Do I need to use another array for the cards?

Answer (score 0):

You can add display flex to the parent div in your render method as default `flexDirection = 'row'`

```
render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div> loading ... </div>;
    }
    if (!this.state.image.length) {
      return <div> didnt get an image</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div style={{display:"flex"}}>  //added display flex
        {this.state.image.map((img) => (
          <div>
            <div>
              {" "}
              <Display
                showImage={img.url}
                showTitle={img.title}
                showAlbum={img.albumId}
              />{" "}
            </div>
            <div key={img.id}>
              <ul></ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```